# Form submit in a foreach

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have a form which contains a foreach. This is my code:

```
<table style="direction: rtl;text-align: right;width: 1500px;font-family: tahoma;" align="center">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th style="width:5%; ">#</th>
    <th style="width:20%;">Name</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Buyer Code</th>
    <th>User Code</th>
    <th>Check</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php
  $i=1;
  foreach($Items as $Item)
  {
    echo '<form method="post" action="/provider/provider/checkUserCodeValidation">
    <tr>
      <td>'.$i.'</td>
      <td>'.$Item->getUser()->getFullName().'</td>
      <td>'.$Item->getCreationDate(true,'Date').'</td>
      <td>'.$Item->getBuyerCode().'</td>
      <td><input name="userCode" id="userCode" value=""/></td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" id="submit_butt" value="Submit"/></td>
    </tr>
    </from>';

    $i++;
  }
  ?>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

The output will be this:

[image]

Now what I want to do is, when user inputs an integer into UserCode and clicks submit, it checks the existence of that integer in database. I am handling the process in checkUserCodeValidation (action of the form). The problem is, if any of the fields are filled, it sends the value of userCode as null. But the last one works. What should I do to submit each one individually?

**IMPORTANT!!:**  I tried using one button where all the table is in one form, but then the problem was that it sends an array which will be a pain in head because I have to implode it and stuff later in my function. So Please help me on this, if you have any solution via Javascript, that will be also appreciated.

Cheeeeers

Comment: I think If you are trying to use  **javascript/jquery/ajax** than you don't need multiple forms.

Comment: First off all there are several things needs to be improved first like you need to add item id in each row so change submit button to anchor with href contains form action url with item id in it.

Comment: Alright, i did it, then what?!

Comment: Then simply you need to perform ajax onclick of anchor to validate your usercode and it's done!

Comment: You don't need a form if you're using `jquery/ajax`.

Comment: It's ok... Let me know if you stuck somewhere.

Comment: Might want to fix that `</from>` to `</form>`

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola you here? I'm stuck!

Comment: ok update your question with the problem you are facing..

Comment: It's fixed!
Thanks for your concern

Answer (score 1):

You have to give a unique id to each input. So you get all values.

Other way is you make each line a form.

Ajax would be the best solution, but in this case the input type must be button instead of submit. Then you have to define the click handler, which makes the ajax call. Here is jquery doc for ajax post: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/
You can do it in vanilla js too: http://vanilla-js.com

Comment: I prefer the second way you said! And I think I'm doing that since each <tr> is in a form!

Answer (score 1):

yout text box id are same

so add any dynamic value to your textbox and name

like

```
 <input name="userCode[]" id="userCode<?php $i ?>" value=""/>
```